# WinForms Charting: LiveCharts deprecated, considering OxyPlot — Any Alternatives?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, live, oxyplot

Currently working on a WinForms student project (an expense manager) (with .NET 6.0), I need to find an alternative to LiveCharts as it's deprecated.

After some research, i'm using OxyPlot, but it is not very customizable, i'm looking for something that match with modern GUI

my current graphics tab :

[graphics tab of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2QWm.png)

code link: https://github.com/marinVcq/wallet-manager-Csharp

thx

Comment: If you're actually referring to [LiveCharts](https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts), it's not deprecated, it just built for .NET Framework. The new version, [LiveCharts2](https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/LiveCharts2), though it's still a Release Candidate, is built for .NET 5+

Comment: ok thx i will check